# match zeros including decimals with RegEx .NET

Tags: .net, regex, zero

I have a textbox that accepts up to 7 characters. I need to make sure the value isn't accepted if it is all zeros before and/or after the decimal place, but i can't figure out the pattern

e.g 000, 00.000, 0.0000 etc.

cases such as 0.001, 0.1 etc can be allowed

have tried ^[0] but this didnt allow for single zero, or didnt allow for combinations such as 0.001

Comment: Why not show us your failed attempts so we can improve on them?

Comment: What type of .NET? ASP.NET? WinForms? Does your validation need to happen on the client side, server side, or both?

Comment: and the validation occurs client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?=.*[1-9])\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

This regex will accept strings meeting the following conditions:

- There must be a digit from 1-9 in the string - `(?=.*[1-9])`
- It must begin with one or more digits - `\d+`
- It may optionally end with a period and one or more digits - `(\.\d+)?`

It will match these strings:

- `42`
- `42.42`

It will not match these strings:

- `0`
- `0.0`
- `42.`
- `.42`

[See it in action here.](https://regex101.com/r/OFsxdY/1)

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It Because that is what this answer does.

Comment: @KendallFrey `(?=.*[1-9])` should be `(?=^[1-9]+$)`..that is wrong

Comment: Like Fake.it says, this won't match all of your allowed cases.

Comment: @JeffWalker Which ones won't it match?

Comment: ah i see, it won't match cases such as 0.01

Comment: @KendallFrey `0.043`,`0.04`,`000000.04` should not match..but it is matching

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It No, those should match.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my refiddle was saved as a private fiddle. The links should work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
[0.]*
```

will match blank, zeroes, and decimal points. Not exactly what you asked for, but will probably work in your case.

Actually you probably want to match something that isn't just zeroes.

```
\d*[1-9]\d*(?:\.(?:\d*[1-9]+\d*)?)?|\d+\.\d*[1-9]+\d*
```

It will match some number before the decimal (at least one non-zero) with an optional decimal and some numbers. OR, some numbers, a decimal, then some numbers (at least one non-zero).

Comment: hi, this still allowed the zeroes to go through

Comment: The first one matched zeroes. Pretty much the opposite of what was asked for. The second one will do it.

Comment: yea tried the second one, works well although it will fire the error if something like 1.0 is entered. Although that part I'll work on myself

Answer (score 0):

The regex for this is fairly simple:

```
@"^(?![0.]*$)\d*\.?\d+$"
```

However, **regex is not what you should use for this.** If you're working with ASP.NET WebForms, you should use a CompareValidator:

```
<asp:CompareValidator id="Compare1Validator1" runat="server" 
       ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
       Operator="DataTypeCheck"
       Type="Double" />

<asp:CompareValidator id="Compare1Validator2" runat="server" 
       ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
       Operator="NotEqual"
       Type="Double"
       ValueToCompare="0" />
```

If you're using C#, use `double.TryParse` and/or string functions:

```
var str = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
var textBoxValue;

if (!double.TryParse(str, out textBoxValue)) || textBoxValue == 0)
{
    throw new Exception("Input was not a properly-formatted, nonzero number.");
}
```

Comment: I don't think 1.0 will be matched, and it should be.

Comment: @KendallFrey - I misinterpreted the question. I thought he was trying to block trailing zeroes after the decimal point. I'll edit.

Comment: Your C# is fine, but I think your regex is still broken. Now 0.1 will not match.

Comment: @KendallFrey - Typo, sorry. Can't believe I left out the `$`. It works now; tested at http://fiddle.re/tdcp